# How to attach more than one agent to a node in tcl ns2?

Tags: tcl, agent, ns2

I want to attach a TCP agent with mobile nodes and sink agent to static node. After few seconds TCP agent should attach with static nodes and sink agent should attach with mobile nodes. Is there a way to attach more than one agent to a node in tcl?

Comment: ? Which other agent (besides tcp) do you want to add ? ... May be found in an already existing example. All ~2000 examples : `all_tcl-examples-2.tar.gz`  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNUUpUYWJ6TTdseWc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I want to add tcp and sink agents to each node. At the start of simulation, tcp agent is attached to few nodes while sink agent is attached to other remaining nodes. After some time, sink agent nodes should send tcp traffic so they should attach tcp agent to themselves and other (initial) tcp agent nodes should attach sink nodes.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add tcp and sink agents to each node

There are 4723 entries with `tcpsink, TCPsink` in the ~2000 examples `all_tcl-examples-2.tar.gz`  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNUUpUYWJ6TTdseWc/view?usp=sharing ( `$ grep -i tcpsink *` )  ( `$ grep -i tcpsink * | wc` )

And files with both `tcp` and `sink`, e.g. `grep -l tcp * | xargs grep -l sink` : 540 files.tcl. ( Some of those are using none default protocols.)

Basic examples : 01-2fa-seed.tcl, 
01-2fa.tcl, 10.tcl, 4node.tcl, 
aodv-10.tcl .... etc. etc.